# Proper mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have no clue as to how to properly write this in raw sql, so I'll try and supply as much clear information as I can.

**Goal in "english"**

I would like to select the **value** column..

in **site_tmplvar_contentvalues**..

where **contentid = 8** and **tmplvarid = 1**

Comment: There's no dumb questions, only dumb people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `value` FROM site_tmplvar_contentvalues WHERE contentid=8 and tmplvarid=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Goal in "english"

<s>I would like to</s> **select** <s>the</s> **value** <s>column..</s>
<s>in</s> **from site_tmplvar_contentvalues**

**where contentid = 8 and tmplvarid = 1**

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you couldn't google/search SO for basic SQL syntax...

```
select `value`
from site_tmplvar_contentvalues
where contentid = 8 and tmplvarid = 1
```

Comment: yah yah yah, i did, and i figured it out, but i was curious what the optimus derek kromm would suggest.

Comment: Also you're answer returns an empty set, but this `select value from `site_tmplvar_contentvalues` where (`site_tmplvar_contentvalues`.`tmplvarid` = 1 AND `contentid` = 8);` works. What may be the difference?

Answer (score 1):

A join is used to select values from more than one table. You have only one table here so the SQL would be

```
SELECT `value` 
FROM `site_tmplvar_contentvalues` 
WHERE contentid = 8 AND tmplvarid = 1
```

If you really need a join please give us some more information about the tables and the related fields in those tables.